# How to add a "where" to Hibernate many-to-one?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I currently have a many-to-one relationship set up from class Exp to class Fin like this:

From Exp.hbm.xml:

```
<many-to-one not-found="ignore" cascade="none" update="false" insert="false" 
unique="false" class="model.Fin" name="Fin"
column="SAK_EXP" property-ref="SakTrans" />
```

What I need to do is add a restriction to this.

In class Fin, there's a property `IndCrDb`, and I only want to create the many-to-one relationship with Fin where this property has value 'C'.

```
<property name="IndCrDb" column="IND_CR_DB" type="string"
 not-null="false" length="1" unique="false" update="true"
 insert="true" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false"/>
```

Is there a way to do this?  I know I could change the setter in Exp.java to not set if the IndCrDb is wrong but that doesn't seem like a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe what you need is an association class.